# Using Java lambda to build map from two maps

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have some code that I need help with ... I'm trying to build a map using two maps as a source and at the same time using java lambdas

```java
Map<String, List<String>> motorsMapping = new HashMap<>();

motorsMapping.put("CAR", Collections.singletonList("AUDI"));
motorsMapping.put("CAR_AND_BIKE", Arrays.asList("AUDI", "BMW"));
motorsMapping.put("BIKE", Collections.singletonList("BMW"));

Map<String, List<String>> models = new HashMap<>();
models.put("AUDI", Arrays.asList("A1", "Q2"));
models.put("BMW", Arrays.asList("X1", "X5"));


motorsMapping.keySet().forEach(key -> {
     Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
     result.put(key, new ArrayList<>());
     motorsMapping.get(key).forEach(value -> models.getOrDefault(value, Collections.emptyList()).forEach(property -> result.get(key).add(property)));
});
```

I can do that with the foreach that you can see above but I was trying to do it using lambdas ... something like this

```java
Map<String, List<String>> collected = motorsMapping
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> {
        return entry.getValue()
            .stream()
            .map(key -> models.getOrDefault(key, Collections.emptyList()))
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry.getKey(), Collectors.toList()));
    }
)...
```

My desired output would be something like

```
CAR -> A1, Q2
BIKE -> X1, X5
CAR_AND_BIKE -> A1, Q2, X1, X5
```

But I cannot get my head around it

Answer (score 3):

As you've tagged this question under `java-8` I'm assuming you have Java 8 and don't have access to `flatMapping` in Java 9. In `java-8` you can do following using :[`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-)

```
Map< String, List< String > > collected = motorsMapping.entrySet( )
            .stream( )
            .collect( Collectors.toMap( Map.Entry::getKey
                    , motorMap -> motorMap.getValue( )
                                    .stream( )
                                    .flatMap( value -> models.get( value ).stream( ) )
                                    .collect( Collectors.toList( ) ) ) );
collected.entrySet( ).stream( ).forEach( System.out::println );
```

Here's the output:

```
CAR_AND_BIKE=[A1, Q2, X1, X5]
CAR=[A1, Q2]
BIKE=[X1, X5]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here is one using the Java 9 methods `Map.entry()` and `Collectors.flatMapping()`:

```
Map<String, List<String>> collected = motorsMapping.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                .map(i -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), models.get(i).stream())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                Collectors.flatMapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

If you are limited to Java 8 you can use this approach:

```
Map<String, List<String>> collected = motorsMapping.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().flatMap(i -> models.get(i).stream())
                .map(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), i)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

The last one uses `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry()` instead of `Map.entry()`.

Both solutions use `flatMap()` to get the list of models for each key. After that the use `flatMap()` again to get the key for each model. Finally both use `Collectors.groupingBy()` to get the result:

```
{
  CAR_AND_BIKE: [A1, Q2, X1, X5],
  CAR: [A1, Q2], 
  BIKE: [X1, X5]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The task could possibly be attained with something as simple as `replaceAll` such that:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = motorsMapping;
result.replaceAll((vehicle, categories) -> categories.stream()
        .flatMap(category -> models.getOrDefault(category, Collections.emptyList()).stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```